# Can I use the email address in the body of the email automatically

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I'd like to create a signature with an distinct trackable URL.  Ideally the link would be something like `www.domain.com?Email=$EMAILADDRESS`

Where the $EMAILADDRESS is the current email address being sent to.  Obviously that can change if there's a way to do this, the rest of the URL is just to tell the website what the data is.

Is this possible in Outlook?

Answer (score 2):

You could trigger a macro to be run when you click on the "Send" button which then directly modifies the content of the email.

As a starter for ten:

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim email As String

    ' Don't stop for errors
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Get STMP email address of first recipient of email.
    email = Item.Recipients.Item(1).PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E")

    ' If that fails, then use blank ("") instead
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then email = ""

    ' Work out what type of email it is and then replace $EMAILADDRESS in
    ' the body to that of 'email'
    Select Case Item.BodyFormat
        Case olFormatHTML
            Item.HTMLBody = Replace(Item.HTMLBody, "$EMAILADDRESS", email)
        Case olFormatRTF
            Item.RTFBody = Replace(Item.RTFBody, "$EMAILADDRESS", email)
        Case Else
            Item.Body = Replace(Item.Body, "$EMAILADDRESS", email)
    End Select

    On Error Goto 0

End Sub
```

If you put `$EMAILADDRESS` in your email (eg. your signature) then it be replaced by the senders email address.

Comment: What happens if there are more than 1 recipient :)

Comment: I wasn't sure what to do with that scenario so I used `Item.Recipients.Item(1)` which basically means the first recipients email address is used.

Comment: I know... I was being difficult  (but I gave the +1 already)  The OP never explains this is a valid situation either. The only logic is to cancel the send, remove the to and then iterate through each one at a time...

Comment: What about if there is a fail, could we make it remove $EMAILADDRESS?  @Dave a good follow up question and you're right I hadn't thought about it, but I think on the whole the solution is about as perfect as I will get.  The first email address would be my preference.

Comment: Also what other variables can I choose?  Can I pick the first name for example?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me it just prints the literal $EMAILADDRESS

Comment: @Eoin that is a new question

Comment: @Eoin I've updated the code so that if it fails to get an email address then it uses `""` instead - which basically removes `$EMAILADDRESS` from your email

Comment: I've also changed it so that HTML, text and RTF formatted emails should work (rather than just HTML) - although I admit I've not properly tested this bit.

Comment: @Eoin Did you get it working? I've just tested on Outlook and it works just fine.

Comment: That's weird.  You don't have to click a button or anything?  I'm using Outlook 2016 if that is different to yours.  Just to double check I'm doing it right... developer > visual basic > this outlook session > Add the code to the bottom.  Click save.  Close.

Comment: Have you changed your Trust Center settings? File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center settings -> Macro Settings. You should then either pick "Notifications for all macros" (which will warn you the first time you send an email but not afterwards for that Outlook session) or "Enable all macros" (which won't show anything). The other two options won't allow the macro to run.